# A problem occurred configuring root project 'firebase_auth'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, apk

my error

I was unable to build an apk release file, I completed the application for a while without error, just a few days later I received this error when building the application, please show me how to get out of it, I tried for 4 hours and got nothing.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':moneytextformfield:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

   > Android resource linking failed

     C:\Users\HaAnh\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d184951b898fabeaa0294fd3e5d63233\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.



     C:\Users\HaAnh\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d184951b898fabeaa0294fd3e5d63233\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.





* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 25s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           26.3s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_auth...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                         3.0s


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'firebase_auth'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

The plugin firebase_auth could not be built due to the issue above.
```

this my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  floating_action_bubble: ^1.1.0
  expansion_card: ^0.1.0
  introduction_screen: ^1.0.8
  #cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3

  google_sign_in: ^4.0.4
  #apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  firebase_database: ^3.1.5
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^1.4.1
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.6.0
  community_material_icon: ^3.5.95
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+4
  image_cropper: ^1.2.1
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.2
  dio: ^3.0.9
  giffy_dialog: ^1.7.0
  #firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
  #firebase_messaging: 6.0.13
  #flutter_local_notifications: 1.4.0
  #cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  cached_network_image: 2.0.0-rc.1
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  intl: ^0.15.7
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^1.0.0
  moneytextformfield: ^0.3.5+1
  flutter_money_formatter: ^0.8.3
  time_formatter: ^1.0.0+5
  #firebase_auth: ^0.11+1+10
  #cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
  #google_sign_in: ^4.4.1
  mime: ^0.9.6+3
  http_parser: ^3.1.4
  flutter_spinkit: ^3.1.0
  numeric_keyboard: ^1.0.0
  beauty_textfield: ^0.0.1
#  ^3.2.4
  shared_preferences: any
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  http: any
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

I want to fix that without affecting the code inside I'm afraid of errors because I ran out of processing time.
Thanks for stopping by, even though there's only one ray of light I hope to hear from you.

-- upodate
After I did "flutter run", the error occurred again

```
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an **android configuration** problem.

The solution is to add the **dependencies** to your android project.

The first step is to follow the instructions on Firebase Auth's [pub.dev page](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth)

You can do this by adding the following lines to your `android/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
  // Example existing classpath
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
  // Add the google services classpath
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
}
```

and adding the following line to the bottom of your `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The next thing to do is add the Firebase Auth plugin to your **android implementations**

To do this you should follow the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries)

Comment: I checked there was nothing missing, the only difference was
``` classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' ```
Do I need to downgrade version?

Comment: This is a bit of a shot in the dark but have you tried "flutter clean"

Comment: "flutter clean" how to do it

Comment: I updated an error after I entered the terminal and ran the "flutter run" command line

Comment: You can do it by running the command "flutter clean" in the same way you would run the command "flutter run"

Comment: ```Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.```
A new error occurred, I cried

Comment: A few things to check here:
1. Make sure your flutter is updated, you can run the command "flutter upgrade" to get the latest.

2. Make sure you are running the "flutter build apk" command from the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

## FLutter - Firebase

#### Step -1

run this command in your project inside terminal. It will clean all the dependencies

```
flutter clean
```

#### Step -2

It will install all the dependencies again but fresh

```
flutter pub get
```