# A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, firebase-authentication

I've been working on a flutter app. Recently I had to re install everything in my pc and ever since then, this error keeps popping up:

> Launching lib/main.dart on SM G615F in debug mode... lib/main.dart:1
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':firebase_auth:classpath'.

> > Could not load module metadata from /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.96/descriptors/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.50/a8be1fe3b3911d3d3425fe720cf42835/descriptor.bin
> > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

> > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

> > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type  org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

> > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I have added all the dependencies necessary:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.0+2
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.15.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.16
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.14
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  get: ^4.6.1
```

Even the necessary lines in both app level and android level `build.gradle` are present. There doesn't seem to be any solutions present in here for this particular problem so any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried removing the dependencies that are throwing the error (shared_preferences, intl_phone_number_input, fluttertoast, firebase_auth, firebase_core, cloud_firestore) and it worked. Then I added the dependencies again and reloaded the app without stopping it and it still worked fine. But when I stopped the app and restarted again, it threw the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A problem occurred configuring root project 'firebase\_auth'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608469/a-problem-occurred-configuring-root-project-firebase-auth)

Comment: @OsvaldoLópez No, I already checked all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with the latest version of flutter. I was using 2.10.5 before and it got updated when I had to reinstall everything. I downgraded it to an older version and cleared the cache and everything got fixed.